# programmatically retrieve element out of nested list

Tags: python

Used following example to retrieve element out of a nested list. This code needs to be extended with more elif statements when the list has a deeper nesting. Question is this a proper solution, or is ther a better was to do it.

```
m_list_test = [0, 1, [2.0, 2.1], [3.0]]


def get_list_element(m_list, idx1=None, idx2=None):
    if idx1 is None and idx2 is None:
        return m_list
    elif idx2 is None:
        return m_list[idx1]

    else:
        return m_list[idx1][idx2]


print(get_list_element(m_list_test))
print(get_list_element(m_list_test,2,1))
```

Output Will be:

```
[0, 1, [2.0, 2.1], [3.0]]
2.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write more "universal" solution using packing arguments:

```
def get_list_element(source, *indexes):
    for index in indexes:
        source = source[index]
    return source
```